# Ionic/Firebase: Log in after logging out doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication, ionic-view

I am building an [Ionic/Phonegap](http://ionicframework.com/) app with a [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) backend.

### **Login**

Followed the example from the [official AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication) for login:

```
// Check sign-in data
$scope.signIn = function(user, password) {

    // Log in
    $scope.auth.$authWithPassword({
        email    : user,
        password : password
    })

    // If successful
    .then(function(authData) {
        console.log('worked');
        // Further code
    }

    // If failure, alert
    .catch(function(error) {

        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Login works fine.

### **Logout**

For logout I also copied the example from the documentation:

```
$scope.logout = function() {

    // Manually disconnect from database
    Firebase.goOffline();

    // Log user out
    $scope.auth.$unauth();

    // Go to landing page
    $state.go('signin');
};
```

Seems to work as well (when I'm asking for the current authentication state of the user after logging out $getAuth() returns null).

### **Login after Logout**

But if I'm now trying to log in again, nothing happens - no error, no success message. So neither of the console.logs triggers.

I need to close and open the app again or refresh the browser window in order to be able to log in again. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

---

**Versions**

Using the latest versions:

Ionic 1.2.4

Firebase 2.4.0

AngularFire 1.1.3

Comment: Have you tried removing the Firebase.goOffline() from logout?

Comment: I was stupid enough not to. It's working now, thanks a lot. Do you want to provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Firebase.goOffline()` from your logout. If you want to manually manage Firebase connection then you should consider adding `Firebase.goOnline()` during login.

Auth.$unauth() will take care of logging out the user, you do not have to disconnect Firebase manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!